# OpenID based SSO with WSO2 Identity Server

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

Unable to get OpenID based SSO using WSO2 identity server. I have followed a Blog post given by the Suresh Aththanayaka, but after entering `https://localhost:9443/openid/admin` as your OpenID identifier. It will not redirecting to the Identity Server page. It shows a blank page.
Please help me.

Comment: I have followed the same steps and I was successfully redirected back to the webapp. Which section you were not able to follow exactly?

Answer (score 1):

I think issue in your client application.
I tried it in WSO2 Identity server 4.6.0 [1] it works fine for me.
Please find the latest sample here[2]

[1] http://wso2.com/products/identity-server/
[2] https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/branches/turing/products/is/4.6.0/modules/samples/openid/