# SSO using OAuth2 protocol with Identity Server 4

Tags: .net-core, oauth-2.0, single-sign-on, identityserver4, openid-connect

Both [OpenID based SSO with WSO2 Identity Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10122044/openid-based-sso-with-wso2-identity-server) and
[WSO2 Identity Server: About SSO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29510725/wso2-identity-server-about-sso) do not fully dispel my doubts.

I have two micro services:

1. Orders (available under: mydomain.com/orders)
2. Warehouse (available under: mydomain.com/warehouse)

**Both are available under the same domain.**

Both have their separate Frontend and Backend. (Angular and .Net core respectively)

I would like to provide SSO (Single Sign On) using OAuth2 and Autorization Code + PKCE Flow Grant Type.

I would like to use Identity Server as an implementation of OAuth2 and OIDC.

Scenario:

1. User hits mydomain.com and is automatically redirected to /login where he/she logs in.
2. User is authenticated in orders micro service (got JWT issued for orders) and user clicks a button named "Go to warehouse".
   Expected behavior: User should not be asked for login again.

Questions:

1. Should I use Authorization Code + PKCE Flow?
2. Should I have separate clients (from STS/IS point of view) for example orders_client and warehouse_client?
3. How STS/IS can recognize the user has already been authenticated? Using auth cookie?

Answer (score 1):

1. Should I use Authorization Code + PKCE Flow?

Yes, in Latest OAuth 2.1 you only have to choose between two flows Authorization code flow and the client credentials flow. All other flows are deprecated. So when a user is involved, you should use the auth flow with PKCE.

2. Should I have separate clients (from STS/IS point of view) for example orders_client and warehouse_client?

It depends.

If you have two clients, then the user might need to give consent to two different clients. Perhaps its better that from a users point of view, that they just have to login and give consent to one of the applications. Or if you place a proxy in front of the two services, so the users sees the system as one. Alternatively, you could share the same data protection API key so that the two services could share the same session cookie.

3. How STS/IS can recognize the user have already been authenticated? Using auth cookie?

you as a user have a separate session cookie with IdentityServer, so when you jump back to it after you logged in (perhaps challenged by the second service) then you are automatically loggedin. You might need to give consent, but that can be controlled using the prompt parameter when you do the initial authentication.

Comment: Do you know any articles/books etc that explain (provide more details) about point no. 3?

Comment: Don't have any links to suggest here, I do provide training if you want need more in-depth  help at https://www.edument.se/search?q=identity  You can also read about the prompt parameter in the spec here https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html